# read multiple fasta sequence using external library kseq.h

Tags: c, fasta

I am trying to find fasta sequences of 5 ids/name as provided by user from a big fasta file (containing 80000 fasta sequences) using an external header file kseq.h as in: http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/kseq.shtml. When I run the program in a for loop, I have to open/close the big fasta file again and again (commented in the code) which makes the computation time slow. On the contrary, if I open/close only once outside the loop, the program stops if it encounters an entry which is not present in the big fasta file I.e. it reaches end of the file. Can anyone suggest how to get all the sequences without losing computational time. The code is:

```
#include <zlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "ext_libraries/kseq.h"

KSEQ_INIT(gzFile, gzread)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char gwidd_ids[100];
    kseq_t *seq;
    int i=0, nFields=0, row=0, col=0;
    int size=1000, flag1=0, l=0, index0=0;

    printf("Opening file %s\n", argv[1]);

    char **gi_ids=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        gi_ids[i]=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
    }
    FILE *fp_inp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(fscanf(fp_inp, "%s", gwidd_ids) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", gwidd_ids);
        strcpy(gi_ids[index0], gwidd_ids);
        index0++;
    }   
    fclose(fp_inp);

    FILE *f0 = fopen("xxx.txt", "w");
    FILE *f1 = fopen("yyy.txt", "w");
    FILE *f2 = fopen("zzz", "w");

    FILE *instream = NULL;
    instream = fopen("fasta_seq_uniprot.txt", "r"); 
    gzFile fpf = gzdopen(fileno(instream), "r");

    for(col=0;col<index0;col++)
    {
        flag1=0;
//      FILE *instream = NULL;
//      instream = fopen("fasta_seq_nr_uniprot.txt", "r"); 
//      gzFile fpf = gzdopen(fileno(instream), "r");
        kseq_t *seq = kseq_init(fpf); 
        while((kseq_read(seq)) >= 0 && flag1 == 0)
        {
            if(strcasecmp(gi_ids[col], seq->name.s) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(f1, ">%s\n", gi_ids[col]);
                fprintf(f2, ">%s\n%s\n", seq->name.s, seq->seq.s);
                flag1 = 1;
            }
        }
        if(flag1 == 0)
        {
            fprintf(f0, "%s\n", gi_ids[col]);
        }
        kseq_destroy(seq);
//      gzclose(fpf); 
    }
    gzclose(fpf); 

    fclose(f0);
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        free(gi_ids[i]);
    }
    free(gi_ids);

    return 0;
}
```

A few examples of inputfile (fasta_seq_uniprot.txt) is:

> P21306
>           MSAWRKAGISYAAYLNVAAQAIRSSLKTELQTASVLNRSQTDAFYTQYKNGTAASEPTPITK
>   P38077
>           MLSRIVSNNATRSVMCHQAQVGILYKTNPVRTYATLKEVEMRLKSIKNIEKITKTMKIVASTRLSKAEKAKISAKKMD
>           -----------
>           -----------

The user entry file is 
P37592\n
Q8IUX1\n
B3GNT2\n
Q81U58\n
P70453\n

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears a bit different than you suppose.  That the program stops after trying to retrieve a sequence that is not present in the data file is a consequence of the fact that it never rewinds the input.  Therefore, even for a query list containing only sequences that are present in the data file, if the requested sequence IDs are not in the same relative order as the data file then the program will fail to find some of the sequences (it will pass them by when looking for an earlier-listed sequence, never to return).

Furthermore, I think it likely that the time savings you observe comes from making only a single pass through the file, instead of a (partial) pass for each requested sequence, not so much from opening it only once.  Opening and closing a file is a bit expensive, but nowhere near as expensive as reading tens or hundreds of kilobytes from it.

To answer your question directly, I think you need to take these steps:

1. Move the `kseq_init(seq)` call to just before the loop.
2. Move the `kseq_destroy(seq)` call to just after the loop.
3. Put in a call to `kseq_rewind(seq)` as the last statement in the loop.

That should make your program right again, but it is likely to kill pretty much all your time savings, because you will return to scanning the file from the beginning for each requested sequence.

The library you are using appears to support only sequential access.  Therefore, the most efficient way to do the job both right **and** fast would be to invert the logic: read sequences one at a time in an outer loop, testing each one as you go to see whether it matches *any* of the requested ones.

Supposing that the list of requested sequences will contain only a few entries, like your example, you probably don't need to do any better testing for matches than just using an inner loop to test each requested sequence id vs. the then-current sequence.  If the query lists may be a lot longer, though, then you could consider putting them in a hash table or sorting them into the same order as the data file to make it possible to test more efficiently for matches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Just to confirm that I understand your answer correctly, the input provided by the user is not always sequential i.e. P37592 is in line number 92587 of fasta_seq_uniprot.txt while P70453 is in line number 92523 but both of them are matched provided I open/close the file within for loop and before while loop (as shown by comment //) and the unmatched entry B3GNT2 is not read at all and written into file xxx.txt So, irrespective of the order of entries, the program runs fine if i open/close the fasta_seq_uniprot.txt for 5 times as required by user.

Comment: I already have tried opening/closing the fasta_seq_uniprot.txt only once and then calling kseq_init(seq) just before while loop starts and putting kseq_destroy(seq) after loop ends (uncommented portions).. But it failed to match the last entries-Q81U58 and P70453 since it couldn't match B3GNT2.